# jQuery filters and effects are not working for dynamic data in React JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, filter

I'm learning ReactJs. It is very exciting to work with React Js. But every time I face a lot of trouble to handle the JavaScript and jQuery which are present inside the template.
This time I am facing problem with a table which has jQuery search filter, automatic pagination etc. All these jQuery effects works fine for the static data. If I add dynamic data for the row of the table, the jQuery effects don't work.
[image]

I have attached a the picture above. The first row is static, but the second and third row came from database. If you mark then you can see that the '+' sign is not visible to 2nd and 3rd row. Even the search bar also show no result for 2nd and 3rd row.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatabaseRow from '../components/Database/DatabaseRow';
import axios from 'axios';
class Database extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
           getData:[]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('alumni/database')
            .then(response=>{
              console.log(response);
                this.setState({
                    getData:response.data
                })
                
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                console.log(error);
            })
    }


 render() {
        const mydata=this.state.getData;
        const eventDetails=mydata.map((mylist)=>{
        return <DatabaseRow
                        full_name={mylist.full_name}
                        dept={mylist.dept}
                        batch={mylist.batch}
                        faculty={mylist.faculty}
                        b_group={mylist.b_group}
                        occupation={mylist.occupation}
                        address={mylist.address}
                        phone={mylist.phone}
                        email={mylist.email}
                        roll={mylist.roll}
                        passoutyear={mylist.passoutyear}/>
          })
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <section class="shadow pb-3" style = {{paddingTop: "7rem"}}>
    <center>
        <h2 class="h2">Alumni Database  </h2>
    </center>
     
</section>
<section style={{marginTop: "5rem", marginBottom: "5rem"}}>
<div className="container">
<table id="responsive-data-table" className="table dt-responsive nowrap table-hover" style={{width:"100%"}}>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Batch</th>
      <th>Faculty</th>
      <th>Blood Group</th>
      <th>Current Position</th>
      <th>Present Address</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
      <th>Roll</th>
      <th>Passout</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <DatabaseRow
                        full_name="Munna"
                        dept="ICT"
                        batch="BICE18"
                        faculty="FST"
                        b_group="O+"
                        occupation="Student"
                        address="DHAKA"
                        phone="9284721"
                        email="abc@gmail.com"
                        roll="2856239084"
                        passoutyear="2002"/>
    {eventDetails}
  </tbody>
</table>


</div>

</section>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Database;
```

this is my parent component and the child component is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class DatabaseRow extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            
                <tr>
                    <td>{this.props.full_name}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.dept}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.batch}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.dept}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.b_group}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.occupation}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.address}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.phone}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.email}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.roll}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.passout_year}</td>
              </tr>
          
        );
    }
}

export default DatabaseRow;
```

database API is ok. It gives result verified in Postman. I have added the  tags containing the jQuery and cdn in index.html, the file is also given below

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="logo.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Web site created using create-react-app"
        />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    
        <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
    
     
        <!-- Material Design for Bootstrap fonts and icons -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons">
    
        <!-- Material Design for Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" integrity="sha384-wXznGJNEXNG1NFsbm0ugrLFMQPWswR3lds2VeinahP8N0zJw9VWSopbjv2x7WCvX" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
        <title>CONNEXION</title>
    
      </head>
      <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <!--
          This HTML file is a template.
          If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.
    
          You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
          The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.
    
          To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
          To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
        -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <script >
          jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery('#responsive-data-table').DataTable({
            "aLengthMenu": [[20, 30, 50, 75, -1], [20, 30, 50, 75, "All"]],
            "pageLength": 20,
            "dom": '<"row justify-content-between top-information"lf>rt<"row justify-content-between bottom-information"ip><"clear">'
          });
        });
    
        </script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.12.6/dist/umd/popper.js" integrity="sha384-fA23ZRQ3G/J53mElWqVJEGJzU0sTs+SvzG8fXVWP+kJQ1lwFAOkcUOysnlKJC33U" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.js" integrity="sha384-CauSuKpEqAFajSpkdjv3z9t8E7RlpJ1UP0lKM/+NdtSarroVKu069AlsRPKkFBz9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>$(document).ready(function() { $('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign(); });</script>
        <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
        
    
      </body>
    </html>
```

if anyone is interest please have a look on this problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is probably not the suggestion you want to hear but you will avoid a lot of headache by stop using JQuery in React projects. Most of the stuff that JQuery provides can be done using generic JS methods as well by now.

Comment: Being new, your suggestion makes me to avoid jQuery for the next time....